# Implementing table joins in the Mobile Apps Node.js backend using SQL

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, azure-node-sdk

Since Azure Mobile Apps does not provide a way to create relationships between tables I decided to create a custom API in my Node.js backend to return data from related tables. The idea was to implement the joins in the backend using SQL, like explained at the [Mobile Services Doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#joins).

The problem is that I'm using the new Mobile Apps and not the old Mobile Services, so the above code does not work anymore. As I understand the architecture changed from Mobile Service to Mobile Apps and the Node.js SDK is an express middleware package. So now we leverage [azure-mobile-apps/src/data](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_data.html) module to handle sql operations.

So I now I have to do something like this to read from a table in a Custom API inside the Node backend:

```
var queries = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/query');

module.exports = {

    "get": function (req, res, next) {

        var myTable = req.azureMobile.tables('TableName');
        var query =  queries.create('TableName');
        query.where({'id':req.query.userId});

        myTable.read(query).then(function(data){
            res.send({ some:  data });
        });
    }
};
```

But since the SQL is not exposed anymore I cannot use the JOIN command to return data from related tables. I would have to to use loops and many request to the database,  which defeats the purpose.

-Is there a way to implement the joins in the backend using SQL on the new Mobile Apps Node.js SDK? Or any other better way?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the `join` sql stmt and leverage a `sqlQuery` object with can contain sql stmt, then use [data.execute](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_data_execute.html#~execute) function to directlu execute the sql stmt. You can refer to the sample https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/samples/custom-api-sql-stmt/api/completeall.js for the similar scenario.

Meanwhile, you can create a View table in Azure SQL database which contain the join stmt, for easy using in Easy APIs scripts and maintaining the View SQL stmt.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Here is my final code: 

`module.exports = {
    "get": function (req, res, next) {

        var query = { 
            sql: 'SELECT @p1 FROM ...',
            parameters: [{ name: 'p1', value: req.query.parameterName }]
            };
            
        req.azureMobile.data.execute(query).then(function (results) {
            res.send({ some: results });
            }, function(error){
                console.log('Found an error: ', error);
            });
    }
};`