# Azure mobile app query inner join with java

Tags: java, sql, azure, azure-mobile-services

I want to use an inner join query with Java and Azure mobile apps, but it looks like api does not let it do operations among the tables. Is there any way to do it?

```
List<ToDoItem> result = table.where()
                            .field("complete").eq(false)
                            .execute().get();
```

As you see, all the operations are over a table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for an inner join in LINQ to SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324/what-is-the-syntax-for-an-inner-join-in-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@shanks, There is a similar SO thread [Implementing table joins in the Mobile Apps Node.js backend using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961075/implementing-table-joins-in-the-mobile-apps-node-js-backend-using-sql) which has been answered and you can refer to.

Assumption that using Node.js as the backend of Azure Mobile App, the steps as below:

1. Define a custom API to execute custom SQL statements via the function [`azureMobile.data.execute`](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_data_execute.html#~execute) with the query of inner join SQL or the query for a view created with inner join sql. You can refer to the subsection `How to: Execute custom SQL statements` of the section [`Custom APIs`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#CustomAPI).
2. Call the custom API via android client, please see the section [`How to: Call a custom API`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/#custom-api).

Comment: sql: "SELECT Id FROM Groups WHERE Members LIKE '%@userId%' and Members '%@friendId%' and type = @roomType ",
            parameters: [
                { name: 'userId', value: userId},
                { name: 'friendId', value: friendId },
                { name: 'roomType', value: type }
            ]
i can not select the row with this statement cuold you review for me what i did wrong